# JWPlayer 7 HLS Stream not working in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, video-streaming, jwplayer, http-live-streaming, jwplayer7

I'm using an enterprise self hosted version of JWPlayer 7.10.4. I use m3u8 HLS streams on my site.

All browsers work except Chrome. It displays this error:
"Error Loading Player: No Playable Source Found"

The version JWPlayer 6 and the same stream works fine in Chrome.

Test page: http://myndos.com/deniz/test.php

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Your videos work fine in the JW stream tester: https://developer.jwplayer.com/tools/stream-tester/

However, it looks like you have a free account, and hls only works with a JW premium account or higher.